# MySQL Workbench 6.3 will not connect to mysql-5.7.7-rc-osx10.9-x86_64

Tags: mysql, database-connection, mysql-workbench, osx-yosemite

I installed both MySQL 5.7.7 and MySQL Workbench 6.3 on a Mac X Yosemite 10.10.3.
I can use the System Preferences>MySQL to start the mysql database and can double check it running on the activity monitor.

When I click on My Connections to connect to the database, it asks me for the root password.  I provide one that I've just created using System Preference > Users and Groups > Logging Options > Master Password Setting and the connection is refused.

I tried to follow many of the answers but couldn't find one that would work.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Do you really mean MySQLBenchMark or rather MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users managed in System Preferences are OS users, not MySQL users. MySQL maintains an own set of users which you have to manage via [certain SQL commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-management-sql.html). Securing the initial setup is described in the docs: [2.9.4 Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html)

Comment: Thanks a million, Mike

Comment: @MarcoPereira if my answer helped you then please accept it (see the check mark) to award the points to me.